# Отображение стран/городов/улиц на русском языке в OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-maps, карты, openstreetmap

При внедрении картографического сервиса в проект, который ориентирован на страны СНГ с возможным расширением на другие страны, столкнулся с проблемой отображения географических имен на русском языке. Разные сервисы отображают имена по-разному. Лучшая ситуация с картами Google- по всем  странам отображается русский текст. В OSM - отображаются карты на локальном языке: Украина/Россия все ок, а вот другие страны отображаются на их родных языках. Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, кто какие сервисы использовал. Предпочтительно конечно бесплатные.

Answer (score 2):

- Если вам нужны "готовые" тайлы, можно взять http://maps.sputnik.ru
- Если хочется иметь полный контроль над стилем карты, то поднимайте свою реплику БД с планетой и мапник как вам подсказал Svirskyy

Comment: Порезали все возможности на спутнике, а жаль, хороший был сервис. В поиске адекватного сервиса...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри на такой сервис как https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ и такое решение как https://gist.github.com/mourner/1804938